# which browsers do not send referer information?

Tags: http, browser

which browsers do not send referer information?

Comment: This technically belongs at superuser.com, but I'm not sure if this would yield better answers there, since the webdevelopers are here, who are generally more technically inclined than webusers.

Comment: @BalusC, I disagree, depending on the intent of the question, this could be about browser detection, which is a programming problem.

Comment: @mikerobi: technically, not intentionally :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Referrer information not sent with a Flash http request
http://training.sessions.edu/resources/SoftwareDesignTips/current/flash.asp

For example, if someone clicks on flash banner linked to your site, request can come to your server without HTTP referrer information

Answer (score 12):

This is not dependent on the browser make/version, but on the browser configuration. All decent browsers with default settings will send it, but the enduser can configure it to not send it. It's also dependent on the environmental software. If you have for example Norton AntiVirus/InternetSecurity installed, then you can configure it to let it block or spoof the referrer header with something entirely different, regardless of the browser used.

Answer (score 3):

All the popular web browsers send referrer headers, at least by default. Some web browsers give their users the option to turn them off. ([Example](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Network.http.sendRefererHeader))