# magento - back button (without using categories)

Tags: back, magento-1.6

there are a lot of back buttons available on the market. Free and paid ones.
But the don't work on my store, because they are all category based.

That's my problem.
In my store i don't use categories, only attributes (in combination with Amasty Improved navigation).

But all back buttons are based on categories.

Can anyone help me to solve this?
I want a back button which goes back to the filtered products (by attributes).

Or does anyone know a extension for this.\

I have magento 1.6.2.

You can check it out on [testwinkel.liefstoereigenwijs.nl](http://testwinkel.liefstoereigenwijs.nl)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you want to avoid using categories, but have you tried using javascript?

```
<a href=”#” onClick=”Javascript:history.back();”>GO back</a>
```

The only problem with this, is that when a user enters your product page from let's say, goolge, the user will be redirected to google.

You can also take a look at this threat: [Back to previous page with header( "Location: " ); in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285031/back-to-previous-page-with-header-location-in-php)