# Get the redirecting URL

Tags: php, url, redirect

I redirect to a URL in PHP using the following code:

```
header('Location: http://site.com/target.php');
```

How do I get the URL that redirected to the target? I tried this code but it's not working:

```
echo $_SERVER["HTTP_REFERER"];
```

Thanks

Comment: try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285031/back-to-previous-page-with-header-location-in-php

Comment: Please do note that the referer could be forged easily.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
<?php echo "http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; ?>
```

Comment: That only shows you the current page's URL, not the referring page.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I know that shows the current page URL.. OP have echoed the code that's why I also echoed it.

Comment: @AdrianWragg he has already the url of referring page and needs the current url and both can be used by session in same site.

Answer (score 0):

Sumit's Code gave you the current URL and you can use it using session :

```
$current_url="http://" . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$_SESSION['url']=$current_url;
header('Location: http://site.com/target.php');
```

Get the URL on the Page :

```
echo $_SESSION['url'];
```

Comment: If you're redirecting to another site, the session object will no longer exist. That will only work on internal redirects.

Comment: @AdrianWragg yes you are right and my solution is only for same domain or same site.

Answer (score 0):

You can't rely on the `REFERER` header, because some browsers will not send it as a security precaution.

If you need to know what URL they requested originally, you could pass it as a query parameter in the `Location` URL. Alternatively, you could store it in a database on the server and pass a key into the database as part of the query string, or similarly store it in a session on the server and pass the session ID as part of the query string.

You may get a more useful answer if you can explain what you're trying to do exactly. Why do you need to know what address they came from, and why do you need to redirect to a different address? Also, are the two addresses on the same website (i.e., the same domain name)?

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ; ?>
```

this link will really help you 
[$_SERVER](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php)

Answer (score -1):

Each time you visit a page store that in `$_SESSION`, so whenever you need the value of the previous page you can view it easily.

Comment: Why should anybody know where were you before you have visited my site? It is not working in that case? Yes, it is not. But why should that work? If you are buying food in a restaurant, they might be interested what did you eat. But why should they know where and what have you eaten before? Isn't that called spying? Isn't that supposed to be a bad thing? So if it is, then why do we consider not supporting a bad thing a problem?

Comment: @Lajor "Why should that work" ... why not ask the OP, he's the one wanting a solution. Not me.

Comment: The op never specified that he wants to track foreign pages. You are assuming.

Comment: "why not ask the OP, he's the one wanting a solution." It was not specified that foreign pages are included into that solution. This is an assumption.

Comment: I'm sorry that you seem to be having difficulty understanding my simple comment. Unfortunately, I have neither the time nor the crayons to explain it further.

Comment: Wow, instead of trying to prove your right you are starting to "doubt" my capabilities. Typical trolling. I have shown you where was your assumption, but it seems it hurts to prove your right or recognize that you were wrong. Good luck for buying your crayons, as I don't buy your comment.