# How to redirect user back to the previous page after they login?

Tags: php, html

I have the following code to redirect user to login page if they haven't log in. But I want to redirect them page to the page they came from after the login, any ideas how to do it?

```
 if(count($user)==0) redirect_page("/login.php");
```

Comment: you need back button code?

Answer (score 4):

You could just add the path to the page they came from to the query string, like this:
`/login.php?returnUri=/the/page/they/came/from.php`

Answer (score 1):

```
header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
exit;
```

**Source:** [Back to previous page with header( "Location: " ); in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285031/back-to-previous-page-with-header-location-in-php)

Comment: Where shall I put this code at? The login page or the page that they came from?

Comment: `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']` can be empty. Don't rely on it.

Comment: Will HTTP_REFERER contain the right value after ```redirect_page()```?

Comment: @Shikiryu yes you are right. It may not work right in this case

Answer (score 0):

Found that the following does work:

```
header("location:javascript://history.go(-1)");
```

(via [Back to previous page with header( "Location: " ); in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285031/back-to-previous-page-with-header-location-in-php))

Answer (score -2):

```
if(count($user)==0){
    echo "<script>JavaScript:history.back()</script>";
}
```

Comment: This is a very poor solution