# c# Website Eventhandler + Browser go Back

Tags: c#, javascript

I want my website to do the onClick event when i click a Button **and** to go back in the browser i am navigating.

Here is a part of my code for the Button:

`button1.Click += new EventHandler(btnAnswerSurvey_Click);
 button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.back(); return false;");`

My problem is that when I click the Button, it goes back but doesn't execute the onClick Event. And if I delete the second line it would do the onClick Event but won't go back in the browser.

is there any way I could do both thing?

Thank you for your help

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285031/back-to-previous-page-with-header-location-in-php

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
button1.Click += new EventHandler(btnAnswerSurvey_Click); 
button1.Attributes.Add("onClick", "javascript:history.back();");
```

I have removed the return false