# Redirect user on last page ( or page he came from ) PHP / JS

Tags: javascript, php

in administration i have simple list of users ( 1 line = 1 user ). And as it used to be I have a button for "EDIT" and button for "DETAIL".
And here it is how each line looks like:

[image]

When user click on detail or edit it redirect him on new address (something like detail/24 (where 24 is ID) or edit/24

Question is: 
 
1# How can I redirect user from detail to page he came from ( because of paginator it is important to redirect on specific page like: list.php?page=4

2# How can I redirect user from edit if he press something like SAVE which basicly reload edit page so he is not able to store it anywhere.

In another words for #2, user is on page list.php?page=4 and click EDIT so he get to something like /edit/32 on that page he make some changes and press SAVE button. When he click this button PHP send FORM and refresh page.

Is there a way to redirect user on page list.php?page=4 without knowing if he press SAVE or not?

3# Is there some other way how to redirect on last page? which simulate "GO BACK" button in browser?

Comment: You can use http_build_query($data) to return data with header

Answer (score 2):

2# [Location.reload()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload)

```
location.reload();
```

1# and 3# [Window.history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history)

```
<button onclick="goBack()">Go Back</button>

<script>
     function goBack() {
         window.history.back();
     }
</script>
```

Comment: Hey @CodeiSir,  
thank you for your asnwer, answer number #1 and #3 looks great however I think I didnt explain #2 correctly.

Please check my edit

Comment: I still don't understand #2 

Comment: I'm sorry man. Looks I'm not good in explenation. Tradicionaly if you have page in PHP / HTML , you send FORM to PHP script so something like : <form action="sendForm.php"> </form> (its simple example but should be enaugh)

So when form is send page reload. Which means that history.back () is the same page as we are atm :)

So if i press save my list.php page is 2 sites back not 1

Comment: I understand. This should be done via PHP. There you can set `header()` with a redirect to the previous page. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285031/back-to-previous-page-with-header-location-in-php `header('Location: ' . $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to redirect before rendering the HTML, I sugest you use header with $_SERVER global variable.

```
if($condition === true)
header('Location: '.$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
```

$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] (http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php) returns the url of the page the user comes from.

Please note header function will only works if there no output before the call.

Hope can help!