# Reload same page after mysqli query finish php

Tags: php, html

I have one php website in which I am using pagination. I am doing some action with mysqli query in page. I am redirecting to home page after finish query using header with below code.

```
header( "Location:manage_quotes.php");
```

I want stay in same page after finish query. I have tried many solution from stackoverflow but not got any proper solution. Anyone can please suggest me solution for this ?

I have tried

```
$currentpage='http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
header( "Location:".$currentpage);
```

but due to I am using query with page its reloading that query page instead of url on which I was before perform action.

Thanks

Comment: State the solutions you've tried out. And FYI, to stay on the same page,  remove the `header()` line

Comment: The answer is in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48251817/join-value-in-php-for-reload-page

Comment: Hi @Akintunde007! thanks for comment. Can You please check my edited question. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Back to previous page with header( "Location: " ); in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285031/back-to-previous-page-with-header-location-in-php)

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a space after the colon.
Additionnaly, add a `exit()` call to avoid extra execution of code.

```
header("Location: manage_quotes.php");
exit(0) ;
```

Comment: Hi ! thanks for answer. Can You please check my edited question. Thanks

Comment: What your `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` variable contains ?

Comment: means ? its like domain.com/mypage.php?page=3