# How can I add destination after login?

Tags: php, authentication, session, redirect, session-variables

I am having this problem, when someone enters the page that requires login, so the page will redirect the user to the login page, after the user completes login step, he/she should be redirected to previous page from he/she was redirected to login page.

Here is a condition on all **login required pages**:

```
<?php
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
    header("Location: login.php);
}
?>
```

What can I add to redirect the user to previous page after successful login?

Comment: Already solutions are there - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5285031/back-to-previous-page-with-header-location-in-php.

Comment: @RajkumarR - That's not a good solution since it depends on the HTTP_REFERER header, which is know for not being reliable. Not only can it be manipulated/overwritten by the client, but for privacy reasons, some routers/firewalls/clients don't always send it with the request. A better solution would be to store the current page URL in a session before redirecting to the login page. Then on a successful login, redirect the user back to the URL stored in the session (and remove it from the session).

Comment: Thanks @Magnus Eriksson I have no problem now. My page is now going to the correct page.