# Detecting a source view from the controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc, view

Is it possible to recognize the view/page name from which a form was submitted to Action ?

For example, lets say I have two Views: `AddInfo` and `EditInfo`
Both views have a form that I would like to submit to

```
@Html.BeginForm("SaveInfo","Info")
{
 ...
}
```

Inside of the `SaveInfo()` method I would like to recognize whether the submit/request came from `AddInfo` or `EditInfo` view.

```
public ActionResult SaveInfo(FormCollection collection)
{
 if(...I got here from AddInfo View)  <----- ?
 {
  ..do something 
 }
}
```

Is it possible ?

Thanks

Comment: Just add a hidden field.  (and remember that a hostile client can modify it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Add/Edit forms are at different pages on your site, then you can use `Request.UrlReferrer` to check where it came from.  That is, something like:

```
bool sourceIsAddForm = 
  (Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri.IndexOf("/add", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) != -1);
```

Comment: Thank you. This is more elegant than using a hidden field.

Comment: @Shenaniganz: Note that not all browsers send referrers.

Comment: uhhh. not really a solution then :( Hidden field then ?

Comment: @SLaks which browsers don't send referrers?  (self-answer: they all do, but the user can switch off sending the referrer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2668821/which-browsers-do-not-send-referer-information)